# Sum of diminishing series with constant addition

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am not sure how to derive the formula for this example, although I suspect something from the annuity <strike>pension (not sure if that is the correct English word)</strike> formulas.

I have a start value of 1000. Each year the amount is reduced by a factor of 0.9. At the end of the year 90 are added to the reduced value. What is a formula to calculate the value at the end of 10 years.

So one way to solve this is to to it step by step:

$s(0) = 1000$

$s(n) = s(n-1)*0.9^n + 90$

Using a spreadsheet I calculated the final value.

$s(10) = 934.87$

How can I derive an analytical formula for this?

Comment: In regards to the correct English word, a pension could describe this, but the more generally used term is **annuity**.

Comment: @KSmarts - Thank you for that too. I will edit the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $s(n)=s(0)0.9^n+90\cdot 0.9^{n-1}+90\cdot 0.9^{n-2}+\dots 90$, where each term after the first comes from the decay of each added $90$.  This is a geometric series which we can sum, getting $$s(n)=s(0)0.9^n+90\frac {1-0.9^n}{1-0.9}$$

Comment: I think I understand the derivation now again. Thank you very much!